# SQL/js - Select the X value WHERE Y

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am learning how to code and I have a table named `locations` that looks like this:

| id | name | X | creatorId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 323 | 5 |
| 2 | name2 | 213 | 5 |
| 3 | name3 | 563 | 5 |
| 4 | name4 | 754 | 2 |
| 5 | name5 | 424 | 3 |
| 6 | name6 | 634 | 4 |
| 7 | name7 | 633 | 5 |

I want to select the row number X where the `creatorId` is X. For example, I want to select the second row where the creatorId is 5 (row 2).

If I use the following query I get access to all the rows WHERE `creatorId` is 5:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE creatorId = @playerId
```

Result:

| id | name | X | creatorId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 323 | 5 |
| 2 | name2 | 213 | 5 |
| 3 | name3 | 563 | 5 |
| 7 | name7 | 633 | 5 |

I am using this in javascript, so the selection can be in js too. The javascript array when stringified looks like this:

```js
[
  {"id":1, "name":"name1", "X":323, "creatorId":5}
  {"id":2, "name":"name2", "X":213, "creatorId":5}
  {"id":3, "name":"name3", "X":563, "creatorId":5}
  {"id":7, "name":"name7", "X":633, "creatorId":5}
]
```

My SQL version is MariaDB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY creatorId ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM locations
)

SELECT id, name, X, creatorId
FROM cte
WHERE creatorId = 5 AND rn = 2;  -- change values here as desired
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Rank Function

```
SELECT id , name, X , creatorId
FROM(
SELECT id , name, X , creatorId, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY creatorId ORDER BY id) rn
FROM #location
WHERE creatorId=5)t where rn=2
```